# Is there a word or expression to describe when " doing something reminds you of someone"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or expression to describe when " doing certain something reminds you of a certain someone" ?

Comment: [_Nostalgia_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgia) comes to my mind, although it is not limited to memories of people. Could you add an example sentence so that we know what type of word/phrase that you are seeking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably describe the action as "reminiscent" of something/someone. For example:

> The way she plays with her hair is reminiscent of Olivia.

Or if in your own context:

> I reminisce about Brad when I go to the bar that we used to go to after work together.

Reminiscence is a word that, depending on context, may have a bit of a somber tone to it. Oftentimes it is used when the situation cannot ever be recreated because the other part/person is missing.